# Finding the 2 greatest and smallest integers in a sequence

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, integer, sequence

I am trying to make a program in class that will find the 2 largest and smallest integers in a given sequence and then print them to the user. 
A sample run would look something like this:

```
Enter the sequence size: 8
Enter the sequence: 5 8 9 12 -6 4 -8 10

The two smallest values are: -8 -6
The two largest values are: 12 10
```

I am not allowed to use sort or array. I've been at it all night but I can't seem to figure it out, could anyone point me in the right direction? This is where I'm currently stuck at - It wont compile because the 'small1' and 'large1' variables aren't initialized, however if I set them to zero they remain as zero in the sample run.

```
int small1, small2, large1, large2, loopcount, sequencevalue;
// Ask the user to enter the first number
cout << "Sequence Size: ";
cin >> loopcount;

// Enter the sequence and start the loop
cout << "\nEnter the Sequence: ";

for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++)
{
    cin >> sequencevalue;

    if (sequencevalue < small1)
    {
        small2 = small1;
        small1 = sequencevalue;
    }

    if (sequencevalue > large1)
    {
        large2 = large1;
        large1 = sequencevalue;
    }
}

// Small variables
if (small1 == 0)
{
    small1 = sequencevalue;
}
else
{
    if (sequencevalue < small1)
    {
        small2 = small1;
        small1 = sequencevalue;
    }
}

// Large variables
if (large1 == 0)
{
    large1 = sequencevalue;
}
else
{
    if (sequencevalue < large1)
    {
        large2 = large1;
        large1 = sequencevalue;
    }
}

// Final Output
cout << "Two smallest values: " << small1 << " " << small2 << "\n";
cout << "Two largest values: " << large2<< " " << large1 << "\n";
```

I greatly appreciate any assistance on this matter, thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe setting the values to zero is the wrong value?

Comment: How would you suggest I initialize them? From what I understand any variable in c++ has a value, including NULL which is just 0 again.

Comment: In C++, the correct initialisation of `small1` would be to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included climits and corrected your code.

Code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Sequence Size: ";
    cin >> count;

    int sequencevalue;

    int large1 = INT_MIN;
    int large2 = INT_MIN;
    int small1 = INT_MAX;
    int small2 = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cin >> sequencevalue;
        if (sequencevalue >= large1) {
            large2 = large1;
            large1 = sequencevalue;
        }
        else if (sequencevalue > large2){
            large2 = sequencevalue;
        }
        if (sequencevalue <= small1) {
            small2 = small1;
            small1 = sequencevalue;
        }
        else if (sequencevalue < small2){
            small2 = sequencevalue;
        }
    }

    cout << "Sequence size is " << count << endl;
    if (0 == count) {}
    else if (1 == count){
        cout << "Smallest value: " << small1 << endl;
        cout << "Largest value: " << large1 << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "First and second smallest value: " << small1 << " " << small2 << endl;
        cout << "First and second largest value: " << large1 << " " << large2 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code example above regards same numbers as unique elements (which may result in same first and second smallest/largest).

If you need to disregard same nubers as unique elements, then for loop should look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    cin >> sequencevalue;
    if (sequencevalue > large1) {
        large2 = large1;
        large1 = sequencevalue;
    }
    else if (sequencevalue != large1 && sequencevalue > large2){
        large2 = sequencevalue;
    }
    if (sequencevalue < small1) {
        small2 = small1;
        small1 = sequencevalue;
    }
    else if (sequencevalue != small1 && sequencevalue < small2){
        small2 = sequencevalue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, though when you do a sequence size of 5 with a sequence of '-4 -4 -4 1 -4' it will not correctly list 1 on the small2 variable.

Comment: actually it depends, if you want unique numbers or not

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my post, my mistake! The final output can use the same number.

Comment: I did not meant the input sequence, but what you consider as answer, if you consider -4 -4 -4 1 -4, second smallest can be defined as second element in ordered sequence regarding the repeating numbers (I solved in this manner) or disregarding (apparently what you desire)

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior since you are using `small1`, `small2`, `large1`, `large2` before they are initialized.

The correct way to initialize `small1` and `small2` will be:

```
int small1 = INT_MAX;
int small2 = INT_MAX;
```

The correct way to initialize `large1` and `large2` will be:

```
int large1 = INT_MIN;
int large2 = INT_MIN;
```

**Update**

Without the presence of a sorted array, the logic to properly update the numbers is not straight forward. Included below is a working program that computes `small1` and `small2` correctly. I'll leave it to you to extend it to compute `large1` and `large2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::istringstream str("8 5 8 9 12 -6 4 -8 10");

   int small1 = INT_MAX;
   int small2 = INT_MAX;

   int loopcount;
   bool small1_found = false;

   str >> loopcount;
   for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; ++i )
   {
      int sequencevalue;
      str >> sequencevalue;

      if ( sequencevalue < small1 )
      {
         int temp = small1;
         small1 = sequencevalue;
         if ( small1_found )
         {
            small2 = std::max(sequencevalue, temp);
         }
         small1_found = true;
      }

   }

   std::cout << "Two smallest values: " << small1 << " " << small2 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Two smallest values: -8 -6
```

Comment: Fantastic! However now that it's initialized my small2 variable is listing as the maximum integer allowed, it seems something is wrong with one of my if-statements?

Comment: This is C++, yet you're suggesting the usage of C macros like `INT_MAX` -- shudder.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `<climits>`

Note the output of this program

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << INT_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << INT_MIN << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now that it's initialized my small2 variable is listing as the maximum integer instead of 0, however i'm not quite sure where i've gone wrong in my if-statements. Any ideas?

Comment: If I were you I would re-write your program with all of the logic inside the loop. Writing in the style that you are there will be four if-statements. Think about the required order of these four operations.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to rewrite it and ended up with basically the same stuff except inside of the for-loop, I'm struggling to figure out where I'm off-track, only four if-statements seems difficult

Comment: Write down a random list of integers on paper, and then perform the loop yourself by only looking at each item one at a time from left to right. Do this a few times.

Answer (score 0):

```
int small1, small2, large1, large2, loopcount, sequencevalue;
// Ask the user to enter the first number
cout << "Sequence Size: ";
cin >> loopcount;

// Enter the sequence and start the loop
cout << "\nEnter the Sequence: ";

for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++)
{
cin >> sequencevalue;
if(i==0)
small1=sequencevalue;
small2=sequencevalue;
large2=sequencevalue;
large1=sequencevalue;}
if(i==1) 
{if(sequencevalue>small1)small2=sequencevalue;
else{
small2=small1;
small1=sequencevalue;
    }
large2=small1;
large1=small2;
}
if (sequencevalue < small1)
{
    small2 = small1;
    small1 = sequencevalue;
}

if (sequencevalue > large1)
{
    large2 = large1;
    large1 = sequencevalue;
}
}
// Final Output
cout << "Two smallest values: " << small1 << " " << small2 << "\n";
cout << "Two largest values: " << large2<< " " << large1 << "\n";
```

Comment: The problem is now after initializing with int_min/max the small2 variable is not listing correctly.

Comment: okay, you're using small1/small2 etc variables without assigning a value to them first
make a if case inside the loop to assign the values to those variables before comparing them
(like if i==0||i==1)do this

Comment: if (small1 == 0)
{
    small1 = sequencevalue;
}
^ this means that if the least integer of the sequence is 0, the last input of the sequence will be assigned to small1
Same goes for large 1

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        // Ask the user to enter the first number
        std::cout << "Sequence Size: ";

        unsigned int loopcount;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> loopcount ) || ( loopcount == 0 ) ) break; 

        int small1, small2, large1, large2;

        // Enter the sequence and start the loop
        std::cout << "\nEnter the Sequence: ";

        unsigned int i = 0;

        for ( ; i < loopcount; i++ )
        {
            int sequencevalue;

            std::cin >> sequencevalue;

            if ( i == 0 )
            {
                small1 = sequencevalue;
                large1 = sequencevalue;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( large1 < sequencevalue )
                {
                    large2 = large1;
                    large1 = sequencevalue;
                }
                else if ( i == 1 || large2 < sequencevalue )
                {
                    large2 = sequencevalue;
                }

                if ( sequencevalue < small1 )
                {
                    small2 = small1;
                    small1 = sequencevalue;
                }
                else if ( i == 1 || sequencevalue < small2 )
                {
                    small2 = sequencevalue;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( i == 1 )
        {
            printf( "There is only one largest value %d\n",
                large1 );
            printf( "And only one mallest value %d\n",
                small1 );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "The first largest value is %d and the second largest value is %d\n",
                large1, large2 );

            printf( "And the first smallest value is %d and the second smallest value is %d\n",
                small1, small2 );
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output can look like

```
Sequence Size: 10
Enter the Sequence: 1 9 8 0 7 6 5 4 3 2
The first largest value is 9 and the second largest value is 8
And the first smallest value is 0 and the second smallest value is 1
Sequence Size: 0
```